# Unable to install a modified apk file

Tags: apk, https

I want to monitor the https traffic of an Android app downloaded from google play.

This app can only be run at Android N and above.

So I use Charles proxy and follow [this document](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) to modify the apk file.

Here's what I have done:

1. Download the app from google play.
2. Use [apk extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en) to get the apk file of the app.
3. Run `apktool d the_app.apk` to extract the apk file.
4. Modify `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml` based on the description of [Charles Proxy document](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/).
5. Run `apktool b the_app` to package the files back to an apk file.
6. Install the apk on my Android phone, whose version is 8.
7. My phone says "App not installed".

Why can't I install the modified apk on my phone?

I've disabled Google Play Protect on my phone.

The `apktool` is installed by following the [description here](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/).

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: It looks like that I have to [resign the apk](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated APK file by apktool needs to be signed before you can install it on a Android phone or emulator:

First you have to create a key-pair for signing stored in a keystore (only required once):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Note this command uses keytool for JDK. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330139/150978)

Then you have to sign the app using `apksigner` which is part of the Android SDK:

```
java -jar build-tools\29.0.3\lib\apksigner.jar sign -ks my-release-key.keystore <apkfile>
```

Now you can install it on the device:

```
adb install <apkfile>
```

If you have the original apk file installed on device you have to uninstall it. because of the changed signature you can install your modified apk file over the already installed original file.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I download `apksinger.jar` for my macOS? I've downloaded the "command line tools only" page [here](https://developer.android.com/studio), but can't find `apksigner` in the file I downloaded.

Comment: Do I have to use [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) to install `apksigner`?

Comment: It seems like that I have to first install build-tools by running `sdkmanager --install 'build-tools;29.0.2'`

Comment: I've found that apksigner is installed in `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796/build-tools/29.0.3`. This path looks is rarely seen to me.

Comment: The app is successfully installed. But I still can't see the https traffic from charles proxy. This strange.

Comment: @Robert It used to be possible to change the package name and install multiple copies of a single app all with their own data, which would allow keeping both the original and modified apps installed. Is this not still possible?

Comment: @l3l_aze This topic has nothing to to with app repackaging. If you have a question on that topic please [post it as new question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: No, sorry for going off-topic -- it seemed relevant because you said they would have to uninstall the original app to accomplish this, which may be avoidable and that could be useful for some people who will find this later or maybe the OP.

Comment: @l3l_aze App repackaging requires more modifications and can be detected by the app easily. A lot of apps don't work if you just change the packageName. Therefore changing the packageName may make such a test way more complicated and error prone than it has to be. On the other hand uninstalling the app is simple and can be done by every body.